# Use Data from One Indicator in Another Strategy

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to backtest a strategy based on the indicator that has a hidden pine code. I only need the data coming out of it (you can see it in the data window) for my strategy, not necessarily the code itself.

How to implement it? input.source only gives the options of high/low/close etc. of the ticker

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one source input in the receiving script. So if you have another such as `src = input(close)` then the external input won't be available.